# Custom Suricata Rules with Datasets of URL Domains in Base64

Tags: dataset, rules, ids, suricata

Any help appreciated on where I am being dumb here?

Trying to configure a custom IDS rule in Suricata using a Dataset (which is an `.lst` file of base64-encoded domains)

[Following this article by IDS tower](https://idstower.com/blog/alerting-on-iocs-using-suricata/)

Additional Suricata docs:
https://suricata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rules/datasets.html#dataset https://suricata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rules/datasets.html?highlight=dataset#dataset

I have tried a bunch of changes and testing, ultimately my rule looks as follows:

```
alert dns $HOME_NET any -> any any (msg:"DNS Query to Malicious FQDN"; dns.query; dataset:isset, domains_iocs, type string, load /etc/suricata/rules/domains_threatfox_base64.lst, memcap 10mb, hashsize 1024; classtype: trojan-activity; sid:1234567891;)
```

This file is included within my `suricata.yaml` config file, both the custom rule itself and the dataset is within `/etc/suricata/rules` directory

Dry run of Suricata config:

```
suricata -c /etc/suricata/suricata.yaml -i <interface>
```

Results in the following not very verbose error of:

```
8/8/2022 -- 23:53:16 - <Error> - [ERRCODE: SC_ERR_INVALID_SIGNATURE(39)] - error parsing signature "alert dns $HOME_NET any -> any any (msg:"DNS Query to Malicious FQDN"; dns.query; dataset:isset, domains_iocs, type string, load /etc/suricata/rules/domains_threatfox_base64.lst, memcap 10mb, hashsize 1024; classtype: trojan-activity; sid:1234567891;)" from file /etc/suricata/rules/ads-ioc-dataset.rules at line 1
```

TYIA!

Answer (score 0):

Hello from IDSTower Developer :)

The Rule syntax is correct and it seems that Suricata is not printing the most useful error message, what you need to check is the following:

1. verify that the IOCs list file contained in the rule exists by running

   ls -lah /etc/suricata/rules/domains_threatfox_base64.lst
2. verify that the IOCs list file contained in the rule is accessible by suricata, the file should be owned by suricata (assuming default installation here)

   sudo chown suricata:suricata /etc/suricata/rules/domains_threatfox_base64.lst

   sudo chmod 644 /etc/suricata/rules/domains_threatfox_base64.lst

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for the response and apologies for the delay on my end :)
I will check my end and see if this resolves it! Thank you so much again!!

Comment: Hello IDSTower!
Please accept my apologies for the delay in my response

I have verified that the list exists.. which are Base64Encoded
I have also verified that both files are owned by "root" (we have Suricata deployed as root) with the appropriate permissions

Any other ideas at all?

# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)"

Comment: Dear, I still believe this might be a permission issue, even if suricata is deployed as root, it will change the running user after startup to the one configured in suricata.yaml (or the default one "suricata"), so could you try changing the owner of the files and settings the correct permissions as above?